# Another way of returning rows if any of the columns has different value for the same id

Tags: t-sql

Is there any other way for returning rows for the same id by joining two tables and return the row if any of the columns value for the same id is different.

```
Select Table1.No,Table2.No,Table1.Name,Table2.Name,Table1.ID,Table2.ID,Table1.ID_N,Table2.ID_N
From MyFirstTable Table1
JOIN MySecondTable Table2 
ON Table1.No=Table2.No where Table1.ID!=Table2.ID or Table1.ID_N != Table2.ID_N
```

In the example above , I have only two columns I need to check but in my real case there are at least 20 .

Is there any other statment I can use instead of enumerating each column in the where codition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...WHERE BINARY_CHECKSUM(Table1.*) <>  BINARY_CHECKSUM(Table2.*)
```

or

```
...WHERE BINARY_CHECKSUM(Table1.Field1, Table1.Field2, ...) <>  BINARY_CHECKSUM(Table2..Field1, Table2.Field2, ...)
```

*this assumes you have no blob fields in your tables

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173784.aspx

Comment: Well, I need only 20/40 columns in the Where condition not the entire table.

Comment: added option for not using all fields

Answer (score 0):

If No is a PK

```
Select Table1.No,Table1.Name,Table1.ID,Table1.ID_N
From MyFirstTable Table1 
except 
Select Table1.No,Table1.Name,Table1.ID,Table1.ID_N
From MySecondTable Table1
```

Comment: Umm I need the codition where Table1.No = Table2.No and is 'except' better for using than Join ?

Comment: You asked for another way.  This is another way.